# Retrieve Data from database and add on the item list of combobox

Tags: vb.net

Hi i could not get the error says invalid to convert to string

here is my code below

```
'open connection
        If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Open()
            ' MsgBox("connection open")
        End If
        '-------
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT ItemDateEntry FROM Item", conn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)

        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

            DateYear.Items.Add(dt.Rows()("ItemDateEntry"))

        Next


'open connection
        If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Open()
            ' MsgBox("connection open")
        End If
        '-------
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT ItemDateEntry FROM Item", conn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)

        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

            DateYear.Items.Add(dt.Rows()("ItemDateEntry").ToString)

        Next
```

I've tried adding ".ToString" but nothing works and nothing display on my combobox

Comment: Try this - DateYear.Items.Add(dt.Rows()("ItemDateEntry")).ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't know how `For` or `For Each` loops work, so you ought to spend some time getting a better grip on that. This:

```vb
DateYear.Items.Add(dt.Rows()("ItemDateEntry"))
```

should be this:

```vb
DateYear.Items.Add(row("ItemDateEntry"))
```

To elaborate, the point of a `For Each` loop is to perform some action(s) for each item in a list. The `For Each` statement itself specifies the list and provides a variable for the current item. You have this:

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
```

therefore `row` is your variable for the current item. If you're not using that variable inside the loop, you're almost definitely doing something wrong.

If you were using a `For` loop instead then you'd have this:

```vb
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
```

and then you'd have to use `i` in the loop to get an item. That would mean using code that looked something like what you had originally:

```vb
DateYear.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i)("ItemDateEntry"))
```

That said, just bind the data:

```vb
DateYear.DisplayMember = "ItemDateEntry"
DataYear.DataSource = dt
```

You can then use the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` to get thetext displayed for the `SelectedItem`. If you want something other than that `String`, you can also set the `ValueMember` to the name of the appropriate column and then get the `SelectedValue`. That will be type `Object`, so you can cast it as whatever type the underlying value is.